# Oracle: Retrive records which have upd_ts less than two year ago

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am trying to get records which have upd_ts within last two years.How can I do this?Is using ADD_MONTHS() is good option?

Comment: Yes, you can use `add_months` to take 24 months from todays date, that can be used to filter on your `upd_ts` column (asuming this is a date)

Comment: somethign like this  
Select * from Table where upd_ts<TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,2*12) ?

Comment: ADD_MONTHS() is probably a good way. But you must have a very clear definition of "less than two years ago". In general a filter like `... > add_months(sysdate, -24)` is a very bad idea. Why? Because the output will depend on the exact moment you run the query. Rather, in business applications, when we ask "for the last two years" we may mean "for the last 24 COMPLETE months" or something similar. If you run the query today, 28 Nov. 2020, at 14:30 India Standard Time, you may ask for the data from 1 November 2018 to 31 October 2020.

Comment: That would mean select every column from the  table where `upd_ts` has a value BEFORE 2 years ago. I suspect you mean `>` or `>=`

Comment: All such requirements can be handled, you just need to be very clear on exactly what you must include.

Comment: @AndrewSayer - actually, "before two years INTO THE FUTURE" - the OP didn't use a negative number for months.

Comment: Doh! Yes, thanks for correcting

Comment: @mathguy. How about using trunc(sysdate)- INTERVAL '2' YEAR

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try.

select * from table_name where trunc(date_column)>=trunc(sysdate- INTERVAL '2' YEAR);